# Add £ sign to a value in a while loop in PHP

Tags: php

I have created a table using data from a csv file using a while loop, however I would like to add a "£" to the 'Rental cost per day field. I have tried various ways with no success. My latest attempt was to try and use an if statement as show below, but this just returns this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\GamesLibrary_2016\index5_stirling.php on line 49

Please help!

```
<?Php 

echo "<html><body><table border=1>\n\n";
$f = fopen("games.csv", "r");
    echo "<tr>
    <th>Car ID</th>
    <th>Make</th>
    <th>Car Model</th>
    <th>Car Description</th>
    <th>Rental Cost per day</th>
    </tr>";


while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    echo "<tr>";
    $£ =("£$line[4]");
    foreach ($line as $cell) {

        if ($cell == $£):
            {echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($£) .  "</td>";} 

        else:
            {echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) .  "</td>";}
    }           

    echo "<tr>\n";
}

fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
?>
```

Comment: you're mixing `{}` with the alternative syntax. that's horribly bad practice. Pick one style and stick with it.

Comment: your line `$£ =("£$line[4]");` is kinda confusing... you cant name a variable with symbols. Also, why are there `:` after the if and else statements ? Don't you come from an other language ?

Comment: As you have probably gathered, I am fairly new to coding :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is far too complicated and lurching between syntax styles like a drunk sailor on day 10 of a 1 day pass:

```
while($line == fgetcsv($f)) {
    foreach($line as $key => $cell) {
      if ($key == 4) {
         $cell = '£' . $cell;
      }
      echo "<td>$cell</td>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, started pointing out syntax problem, but clear exemple is way more clear !

Comment: Also [**The definition of variable naming**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) **Must** be applied.

Comment: Thank you MarkB, I have used your suggestion and it gives the £ sign after the number, but now the data is all on one row?

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused because of this piece:

```
 if ($cell == $£):
        {echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($£) .  "</td>";} 

    else:
        {echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) .  "</td>";}
}
```

Remove the `:`, so it would look something like this:

```
   foreach ($line as $cell) {
        if ($cell == $£) {
            echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($£) . "</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you MHaKvoort, I have corrected my code but it still does not give the £ sign in the rental cost per day field?

Comment: Thank you all, I have now figured out how to get it all in a table. Great help guys. The books just do not cover the stuff you need! Thanks again